# How to render Container Classes conditionally

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, frontend

firstly, this is what is given to me from designer http://www.giphy.com/gifs/hSRrqF5ObsbXH27V09

Basically, there is a `category` which is passed from previous screen. and with some ui interactions, i need to render this screen again and again. the flow is like that: you select a `category`, if it has `subCategories`, let user select one of those `subCategories` before rendering input components. i can make it work with if and else clauses but i feel that this is some how not best practice at all. I just need an advice from experieced developer(i am reletively new to react native.)
So before writing any code with native way, i just want to ask it here so maybe i can learn more about it.

Here is my Screen:

```
  <NewAdHoc
                contentText={'Kategori Secimi'}
                onBackPress={this.handleBackPress}
                showContentText={false}
            >
                <View style={styles.container}>
                    {currentCategory !== null
                        ? (
                            <View style={{ ...styles.flatListContainer, paddingLeft: undefined, paddingRight: undefined }}>
                                <View style={{ marginHorizontal: 20 }}>
                                    <ListViewItem
                                        categoryName={currentCategory.categoryName}
                                        iconName={currentCategory.categoryIcon}
                                        showBorder={false}
                                        key={currentCategory.categoryId}
                                        categoryId={currentCategory.categoryId}
                                        inNewAdScreen={false}
                                    />
                                </View>
                                <Seperator
                                    backgroundColor={colors.SEPERATOR_BCK}
                                    text={'Ilan Turu'}
                                    style={{ paddingHorizontal: 20 }}
                                />
                                {
                                    currentCategory.subCategories.map((subc) => (
                                        <View style={{ marginHorizontal: 20 }}>
                                            <SubCategoryItem
                                                text={subc.subCategoryName}
                                                key={subc.subCategoryId}
                                                showBorder={true}
                                            />
                                        </View>
                                    ))

                                }
                            </View>
                        ) : null}
                </View>
            </NewAdHoc>
```

right now, i am rendering a `category`, a `<Seperator/>` between category and subcategories, and subcategories. what i want is that, when user click on one of the `subCategories`, i will change the `state` to `isSubCategorySelected = true`, `selectedSubCategory= subCategoryId` and then need to render the whole screen like in gif i provided above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**the For those who came here for answer:**

What i did is basically divide and conquer paradigm. I firstly divide my sitution into two main state.

1. `RenderInitialForm()`,
2. `renderAfterSubCategorySelected()`,

those two rendering functions handle the whole process. when a `TouchableOpacity` is clicked, i `setState` with two variables: `isSubCategorySelected = true`, `selectedSubCategory = subCategory`

and in my main `render()` function:

```
    render() {
        const { currentCategory, isSubCategorySelected, selectedSubCategory } = this.state
        return (
            <NewAdHoc
                contentText={'Kategori Secimi'}
                onBackPress={this.handleBackPress}
                showContentText={false}
            >
                <View style={styles.container}>
                    {currentCategory !== null
                        ? isSubCategorySelected
                            ? this.renderAfterSubCategorySelected()
                            : this.renderInitialForm()
                        : null}
                </View>
            </NewAdHoc>
        );
    }
```

if you have any suggestion with my solution, please feel free to contact me.